# Date Time insert table

Tags: php, datetime

I have date/time saved in my sql Table as a column "registertime".

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, firstname, lastname, registerdate FROM users WHERE level < 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_GET['username'], $_GET['firstname'], $_GET['lastname'], $_GET['registerdate']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $firstname, $lastname, $registerdate);
```

I want to use my register date value to figure out how many days ago someone registered from using (date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

```
<?php
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$dayspassed = strtotime($registerdate));
$daysinactive = $dayspassed - $today;
?>
```

I have the date the user registered stored in $registerdate i then want to find out how many days has passed since the $registerdate and current date so i can echo out "This user registered 2 days ago".

Comment: You've no placeholders.

Comment: how you storing date in database? which format?

Comment: date/time is used in the table

Comment: `strtotime(date())` is pointless. why not just `time()`? Forcing a timestamp->string->timestamp conversion is an utterly pointless waste of cpu cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime class

```
<?php
$bday = new DateTime('2016-05-016'); //y-m-d
$today = new DateTime('2010-08-01 00:00:00'); // for testing purposes

$diff = $today->diff($bday);

printf('%d years, %d month, %d days', $diff->y, $diff->m, $diff->d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

output : +2Days

Comment: Then use 

$today = new DateTime("now");
$dayspassed = new DateTime($registerdate);

$interval = date_diff($today, $dayspassed);

Comment: Hasn't worked - 
`$today = new DateTime("now"); `
`$dayspassed = new DateTime($registerdate); `
`$interval = date_diff($today, $dayspassed);`
`echo $interval;`

Comment: echo $interval->days

Comment: nothing echos at all  - `$today = new DateTime("now"); `
`echo $today;` even this echos nothing

Comment: @nathzOO its an object echo will not work try to var_dump();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116111/discussion-between-manidev-and-nathzoo).

Comment: @nathzOO just copy paste and run below code.
$date1 = new DateTime("now");

$date2 = new DateTime('2016-06-20 10:00:00');
$val = date_diff($date1,$date2);

echo $val->days;